# When setting up Apache2 on ubuntu 20.04 for HTTPS do I need to use the <IfModule>?

Tags: https, apache2, configuration

I am setting up HTTPS on a new Apache2 install.

I plan to use the free certs from CloudFlare and install their Origin Cert and Private Key.

Would really appreciate your input.

I have just run a2enmod ssl

```
root@Ubuntu20:/etc/apache2/sites-available# a2enmod ssl 
Considering dependency setenvif for ssl: 
Module setenvif already enabled 
Considering dependency mime for ssl: 
Module mime already enabled 
Considering dependency socache_shmcb for ssl: 
Enabling module socache_shmcb. 
Enabling module ssl. 
See /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz on how to configure SSL and create self-signed certificates. 
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:   systemctl restart apache2
```

and run systemctl restart apache2

The following config has been recommended:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@good-health.ml
    ServerName good-health.ml
    ServerAlias www.good-health.ml

    Redirect / https://good-health.ml/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@good-health.ml
    ServerName good-health.ml
    ServerAlias www.good-health.ml
    DocumentRoot /var/www/good-health.ml

    <Directory /var/www/good-health.ml>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/mycerts/good-health.ml/origin_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/mycerts/good-health.ml/private_key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Looks good to me :)

I have seen `<IfModule mod_ssl>` (or something similar) tags around the `:433`

Should I add those tags?